# What's the best method for migrating a media server from Windows 10 to Ubuntu whilst retaining media files?

Tags: ubuntu, files

I currently have a Windows 10 machine running Plex, operating from an SSD boot drive, which is getting its files from a local [DrivePool](https://stablebit.com) consisting of 3 8TB drives. These drives are pretty much full now and I've just bought 2 more of the same drive on sale.

I'm looking to move over to linux while installing these new drives and but also mainly to take advantage of [this runbook](https://github.com/ahembree/ansible-hms-docker).

I'm happy to lose everything on the SSD as it can all be rebuilt manually after switching to linux, either from the runbook or manual config. The media files in the drivepool on the other hand I don't really have an option for backing up.

What's the best method for migrating to linux in this case? I've seen mergerfs and zfs be thrown around online but not sure how to go about nsetting that up without losing the data.

Comment: Plex has its own support: https://support.plex.tv/

Comment: I don't have any issues with Plex, I can configure that after the migration. My concern is specifically with carrying over 24TB of media from Win10 (using drivepool) to ubuntu without losing it or the JBOD style access.